# FBX models into Directx 11

Tags: c++, fbx

I've just ported over and updated a bunch of FBX model loading code I had that worked with Direct X 10 to try and make it work with Direct X 11. Since that time, the FBX SDK I was using has been updated.

In my old program I linked to the following lib:

```
fbxsdk-2012.2-mdd.lib
```

Now, clearly I can't link to this as I don't have 2012.2 on my system. So, my thinking would be simply changing 2012.2 to 2014.1, but this didn't work and lead to the following error:

```
error LNK1104: cannot open file 'fbxsdk-2014.1-mdd.lib'
```

So I tried to some googleing to see what the updated version of fbxsdk-2012.2-mdd.lib is. But I can't find anything. I tried taking out linking ot the 2014.1 lib but I get the following errors:

> Error 36  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl fbxsdk_2014_1::FbxAssert(char const *,char const *,unsigned int,char const *)" (?FbxAssert@fbxsdk_2014_1@@YAXPBD0I0@Z) referenced in function "public: int & __thiscall fbxsdk_2014_1::FbxArray::operatorconst " (??A?$FbxArray@H@fbxsdk_2014_1@@QBEAAHH@Z)

So, looking in the FBX sample directory I opened up the ViewScene sample to see what it lib it linked to and I see that it wanted the following:

```
libfbxsdk-md.lib
```

So I did the same. But, my program claims it cannot open the file. And I'm at a loss as to what to do next.

Has anyone successfully managed to load FBX models into a Directx 11 application using 2014.1? If so, what do I need to do to get the correct lib linked?

Comment: Are you sure that your library paths are set up correctly. the FBX SDK installs to C:(or whatever)\Program Files\Autodesk\FBX... by default

Comment: Yeah man - my library path is C:\Program Files\Autodesk\FBX\FBX SDK\2014.1\lib\vs2012\x86

Answer (score 1):

For debug configurations just add:

> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\FBX\FBX SDK\2014.1\lib\vs2012\x86\Debug\libfbxsdk-md.lib

To your project properties:

> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Directories